# How can I use my iPad Mini and Android tablet as another two monitors for my notebook?

Tags: multiple-monitors

How can I use my iPad Mini and my Android tablet as another two monitors for my notebook?

How can I use my iPad mini and android table as a secondary and a third monitors of my notebook?

i.e. I want to use another two monitors for my notebook.
and the secondary and the tertiary tablets are using different OSs (Android and iOS)

Thanks.

Comment: You may also find more duplicate questions by using the search tool at [android.se] and [apple.se].

Comment: Also please do not simply delete and re-ask the [exact same questions](https://superuser.com/questions/1570925/how-can-i-use-my-ipad-mini-and-android-table-as-my-sub-monitors-of-my-notebook), that behaviour is considered abusive. Deleted or downvoted questions can also contribute to an automatic ban being applied.

Answer (score 1):

I would check out [Spacedesk](https://spacedesk.net/). I use it and it works pretty well. It's free and for both Android and Apple products. However, as far as I can tell, it's only for Windows Machines. For MacOS, there is [Duet Display](https://www.duetdisplay.com/) (And, actually, Duet Display is for both Mac and Windows)

Hopefully, this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much!  Your answer is as perfect as can be!  Your answer tell me many informations.

Comment: Yay! Glad I could help!

Comment: Could you tell me what can I use when my notebook is run by linux?

Comment: Really thank you for editing my question! I really want to find right sentence.      Thank you very much !!!

Comment: Sorry, I can't find any software that's for Linux.

Comment: Thank you!! Have a great week!